# How to increase the horizontal split window size in Vim

Tags: vim

I have two open files in horizontal mode. How do I increase or decrease the height of either?

```
:30winc > and :30winc <
```

works for the width. But...

```
:30hinc > and :30hinc <
```

doesn't work for the height.

Comment: jesus, i can't believe that worked. thanks!

Comment: Could this question be moved to http://vi.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: whoa, yeah for sure I didn't know about the vi.se!

Answer (score 1):

Use `:30winc`, but use `+` or `-` instead.

Comment: This sounds cool, but I have no idea what you just said. (Neither you, nor the OP have explained what `winc` is all about.)

Comment: Vim is too big for merely one person to understand it all. ;-)